# Flask: How to send data from python script to HTML

Tags: python, flask

I have a python script returning a list and I would like to send those data to HTML for building a appropriate template.

script.py:

```
def database():
 try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DataTeste' user='user1' host='localhost' password='123'")
 except:
  return "Impossible to connect to the database, check your code."

 cur = conn.cursor()
 conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers") 
 rows = cur.fetchall()

 return rows
```

Now I want to receive this script in some template. Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Use [**`Jinja`**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/)

Comment: You really need to add more detail than this to your question. Flask comes prepackaged with a templating library `Jinja2` which you use to render HTML templates. It is also capable of returning json data to AJAX calls... you'll get more relevant responses if you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Render templates

Comment: Render templates is clear for me, me send python script data to some template I didn't find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

script.py

```
def database():
 try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DataTeste' user='user1' host='localhost' password='123'")
 except:
  return "Impossible to connect to the database, check your code."

 cur = conn.cursor()
 conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers") 
 rows = cur.fetchall()

 return rows
```

index.py

```
from flask import render_template
from script import database

@app.route("/")
def index():
    to_send=database()
    return render_template("index.html", to_send=to_send)
```

index.html

```
{%for i in to_send%}
<p> {{i[0]}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Worked! Clear it for me, ``from "script_name" import "function_name"``. Is it?

Comment: Yes , is working like this

Answer (score 1):

You should look in http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/ documentation. It's really simple.

Here is how to do it.

### Python file

```
from flask import render_template
@app.route("/")
def index():
    list_object = ["Hey", "How", "Are", "You"]
    return render_template("index.html", list_to_send=list_object)
```

### HTML file "index.html"

Put this in `body` tag.

```
{% for element in list_to_send%}
    <p>{{element}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The list_object is in a script.py, Do I need return the list in the final function and call it as arg in render_template?