# How to import or call PY code in HTML within django framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, html

I wrote a py file that uses two APIs to retrieve data about current crypto trends. I am trying to import or call the retrieved data in an HTML file do display in my web app.

I have tried using {{% %}} to call the py file, but not sure if I am doing the right thing.

```
import requests

url_usd = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?                    
vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1' \
         '&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h'

url_gbp = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? 
vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1' \
      '&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h '

requests1 = requests.get(url_usd)
results1 = requests1.json()

requests2 = requests.get(url_gbp)
results2 = requests2.json()

for i in range(0, 250):
    coin_id = results1[i]['id']
    coin_name = results1[i]['name']
    changes = results1[i]['price_change_percentage_24h']
    usd = results1[i]['current_price']
    gbp = results2[i]['current_price']

    print("Coin ID: " + coin_id)
    print("Coin name: " + coin_name)
    print("Price per coin in USD: " + "$" + "{:.2f}".format(float(usd)))
    print("Price per coin in GBP: " + "£" + "{:.2f}".format(float(gbp)))
    print("Percentage price change: " + "{:.2f}".format(changes) + "%")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Coin ID: bitcoin
Coin name: Bitcoin
Price per coin in USD: $3461.54
Price per coin in GBP: £2645.04
Percentage price change: 0.82%

Coin ID: ripple
Coin name: XRP
Price per coin in USD: $0.31
Price per coin in GBP: £0.23
Percentage price change: -0.60%
```

and so on for the next 250 coins

I want to now call this data from an html file so it can be displayed on the web app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795723/flask-how-to-send-data-from-python-script-to-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you something to start with; Put it in a class, which returns a dict populated with the data (can also be a plain function)

```
import requests

class CryptoData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usd_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                       "vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                       "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"
        self.gbp_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                       "vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                       "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"


    def get_crypto_data_dict(self, get_it=False):
        crypto_dict = dict()
        requests1 = requests.get(self.usd_url)
        results1 = requests1.json()

        requests2 = requests.get(self.gbp_url)
        results2 = requests2.json()



        for i in range(0, 250):
            crypto_dict[results1[i]['id']] = {
                'coin_name': results1[i]['name'],
                'changes': results1[i]['price_change_percentage_24h'],
                'usd': results1[i]['current_price'],
                'gbp': results2[i]['current_price']
            }


        return crypto_dict
```

Then in view:

```
def crypt_view(request):
    crypto_data = CryptoData()

    context = {
        'crypto_data': crypto_data.get_crypto_data_dict()
    }

    return render(request, 'crypto/crypto.html', context=context)
```

Then in crypto.html (this is an just example):

```
<ul>
     {% for crypto_datum, crypto_value in crypto_data.items %}
        <li>{{ crypto_datum }}
            <ul>

                {% for info, value in crypto_value.items %}
                    <li>{{ info }}: {{ value }}</li>
                {% endfor %}


            </ul>

        </li>
     {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

One problem with this, Anytime someone touches the webpage, you'll automatically send a get request to coingecko.   This can be an issue with rate limits

so you could do instantiate your CryptoData in views.py but outside of your view function.

so a better Implementation which could limit the data update to every 60 second is this:

```
import requests, time
from django.shortcuts import render

class CryptoData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usd_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                       "vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                       "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"
        self.gbp_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                       "vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                       "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"

        self.previous_request = None
        self.crypto_dict = dict()


    def get_crypto_data_dict(self, seconds_to_wait=60):

        if not self.previous_request or self.previous_request+seconds_to_wait < time.time():
            print("requested", self.previous_request, time.time())
            self.previous_request = time.time()
            crypto_dict = dict()
            requests1 = requests.get(self.usd_url)
            results1 = requests1.json()

            requests2 = requests.get(self.gbp_url)
            results2 = requests2.json()

            for i in range(0, 250):
                self.crypto_dict[results1[i]['id']] = {
                    'coin_name': results1[i]['name'],
                    'changes': results1[i]['price_change_percentage_24h'],
                    'usd': results1[i]['current_price'],
                    'gbp': results2[i]['current_price']
                }

        return self.crypto_dict


crypto_data = CryptoData()

def crypt_view(request):

    context = {
        'crypto_data': crypto_data.get_crypto_data_dict()
    }

    return render(request, 'crypto/crypto.html', context=context)
```

WIth this implementation, coingecko api is only called every 60 seconds

EDIT: to display it in the same way you could do something like this:

```
{% for crypto_datum, crypto_values in crypto_data.items %}
    <div>
    <p>Coin ID: {{ crypto_datum }}<br>
        Coin Name: {{ crypto_datum|capfirst }}<br>
        Price per coin in USD: ${{ crypto_values.usd|floatformat:2 }}<br>
        Price Per coin in GBP: £{{ crypto_values.gbp|floatformat:2 }}<br>
        Percentage price change: {{ crypto_values.changes|floatformat:2 }}%
    </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This would look something like this:

```
Coin ID: bitcoin
Coin Name: Bitcoin
Price per coin in USD: $3466.24
Price Per coin in GBP: £2657.72
Percentage price change: 0.16%

Coin ID: ripple
Coin Name: Ripple
Price per coin in USD: $0.30
Price Per coin in GBP: £0.23
Percentage price change: -0.85%

Coin ID: ethereum
Coin Name: Ethereum
Price per coin in USD: $107.27
Price Per coin in GBP: £82.25
Percentage price change: -0.11%
```

Comment: Thank you for this but could you show me how to format the data in order to show it as before? for example to show the prices I added

 "Price per coin in USD: " + "$" + "{:.2f}".format(float 

This was to display to display the $ and £ sign

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the web app that you have.

The simplest way to do it is as Griehle suggested, use flask. It is a very simple framework.

I would also suggest that you move this code in a function and iterate over the number of results you actually get, not for a hard coded number of iterations.