# How to transfer data from Python to HTML

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I was using PostgreSQL with Python and decided to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795723/flask-how-to-send-data-from-python-script-to-html/48795904) it to an HTML file, but the examples I found on Stack Overflow didn't work.

This is my database.py code:

```
import psycopg2
def database():
 try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='****' user='****' host='localhost' password='********'")
 except:
  return "Impossible to connect to the database, check your code."

 cur = conn.cursor()
 conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ******")
 rows = cur.fetchall()

 return rows
```

And home.py:

```
from flask import render_template
from database import database


@app.route("/")
def index():
    to_send = database()
    return render_template("home.html", to_send=to_send)
```

And home.html:

```
{%for i in to_send%
          <p>{{i]}}</p>
          {%endfor%}
```

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: because the html page displays exactly what the code says

Comment: If what you typed is what you have in your html template, then you have a typo. You are missing the closing ```}``` after ```to_send```

Comment: How you are opening the website in browser?

Comment: um i use pycharm and it has button it open in different browsers

Comment: still not working

Comment: also what is @app route used fro